# How do I properly convert the type of a type argument property in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Sorry, I was unsure how to ask the question.

Example code:

```
type account = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
};

type message = {
  id: string;
  account: string;
}

type accountMessageJoin = {
  id: string;
  account: account;
};

function testFn<T, S>(parent: T[], child: S, key: string) {
  return parent.map(p => {
    const newP = { 
      ...p,
      [key]: child[p[key]]
    };
    return newP;
  })
};

const testAccount: { [key: string]: account } = {
  aaa: {
    id: "aaa",
    name: "Sam",
  },
};

const testMessage: message = {
  id: "111",
  account: "aaa",
};

const join: accountMessageJoin[] = testFn<message, { [key: string]: account }>([testMessage],testAccount, "account");
```

What I'm trying to do is join an array of objects with a property that is an id, with the corresponding object for that id, e.g.

```
const exampleWithId = [
  {
    id: "abc",
    account: "123",
  },
];

const exampleWithObject = [
  {
    id: "abc",
    account: {
      id: "xyz",
      name: "sam",
    },
  },
];
```

But my functions type is

```
function testFn<T, S>(parent: T[], child: S, key: string): (T & {
    [x: string]: any;
})[]
```

and my error when I try to assign it to join is:

```
Type '(message & { [x: string]: any; })[]' is not assignable to type 'accountMessageJoin[]'.
  Type 'message & { [x: string]: any; }' is not assignable to type 'accountMessageJoin'.
    Types of property 'account' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'account'.
```

Node: this is supposed to be a generic function so I need it to work for other properties other than "account".

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You have an error on `child[p[key]]` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/we4vKW).  Is that part of your question or not? If it is, you should mention it. If not, you should probably resolve it so it doesn't distract from the question.

Comment: Oh sorry. That error isn't showing up in my VSCode for some reason, I'll try to fix it, but it isn't part of the question, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WG5xMN) meet your needs? (Please test against use cases). If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I think that works for me, I really appreciate your time and effort, thank you. One question though, if I add an additional property to the `Message` type and appropriate data to the `testMessage` variable, but not to the `AccountMessageJoin` type, it doesn't produce an error, is that working as intended? [link](https://tsplay.dev/NnQ0qw)

Comment: Yes, that's working as intended; TypeScript has a [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and its object types are open/extendible and not closed/sealed.  A value of the type `{a: string}` must have a string-valued `a` property but it *may* have additional properties as well.  You don't *have* to annotate variables, sometimes it's better to let the compiler infer types [like this](//tsplay.dev/WybpJw). Anyway can I write up the answer without talking about extra properties? Or is that crucial to this question?